# Python Async Limit Concurrent coroutines per second

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

My use case is the following :
I’m using python 3.8

I have an async function analyse_doc that is a wrapper for a http request to a web service.
I have approx 1000 docs to analyse as fast as possible. The service allows for 15 transaction per second (and not 15 concurrent request at any second). So first sec I can send 15, then 2nd sec I can send 15 again and so on. If I try to hit the service more than 15 times per sec I get 429 error msg or sometimes 503/504 error (server is busy…)

My question is : is it possible to implement smt in python that effectively sends 15 requests per sec asynchronously then wait 1 sec then do it again until the queue is empty. Also some tasks might fail. Those failing tasks might need a rerun at some point.

So far my code is the following (unbounded parallelism… not even a semaphore) but it handles retry.

```
tasks = {asyncio.create_task(analyse_async(doc)): doc for doc in documents}
pending = set(tasks)

# Handle retry
while pending:
    #  backoff in case of 429
    time.sleep(1)

    # concurrent call return_when all completed
    finished, pending = await asyncio.wait(
        pending, return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED
    )

    
    # check  if task has exception and register for new run.
    for task in finished:
        arg = tasks[task]

        if task.exception():
            new_task = asyncio.create_task(analyze_doc(doc))
            tasks[new_task] = doc
            pending.add(new_task)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding another `sleep` tasks into the mix to drive the request generation. Something like this

```
import asyncio
import random

ONE_SECOND = 1
CONCURRENT_TASK_LIMIT = 2
TASKS_TO_CREATE = 10

loop =  asyncio.new_event_loop()

work_todo = []
work_in_progress = []

# just creates arbitrary work to do
def create_tasks():
    for i in range(TASKS_TO_CREATE):
        work_todo.append(worker_task(i))

    # muddle this up to see how drain works
    random.shuffle(work_todo)

# represents the actual work
async def worker_task(index):
    print(f"i am worker {index} and i am starting")
    await asyncio.sleep(index)
    print(f"i am worker {index} and i am done")

# gets the next 'concurrent' workload segment (if there is one)
def get_next_tasks():
    todo = []

    i = 0

    while i < CONCURRENT_TASK_LIMIT and len(work_todo) > 0:
        todo.append(work_todo.pop())
        i += 1

    return todo

# drains down any outstanding tasks and closes the loop
async def are_we_done_yet():
    print('draining')
    
    await asyncio.gather(*work_in_progress)

    loop.stop()
    
    # closes out the program
    print('done')

# puts work on the queue every tick (1 second)
async def work():
    next_tasks = get_next_tasks()
    if len(next_tasks) > 0:
        print(f'found {len(next_tasks)} tasks to do')
        for task in next_tasks:
            # schedules the work, puts it in the in-progress pile
            work_in_progress.append(loop.create_task(task))

        # this is the 'tick' or speed work gets scheduled on
        await asyncio.sleep(ONE_SECOND)
        
        # every 'tick' we add this tasks onto the loop again unless there isn't any more to do...
        loop.create_task(work())
    else:
        # ... if there isn't any to do we just enter drain mode
        await are_we_done_yet()

# bootstrap the process
create_tasks()
loop.create_task(work())
loop.run_forever()
```

Updated version with a simulated exception

```
import asyncio
import random

ONE_SECOND = 1
CONCURRENT_TASK_LIMIT = 2
TASKS_TO_CREATE = 10

loop =  asyncio.new_event_loop()

work_todo = []
work_in_progress = []

# just creates arbitrary work to do
def create_tasks():
    for i in range(TASKS_TO_CREATE):
        work_todo.append(worker_task(i))

    # muddle this up to see how drain works
    random.shuffle(work_todo)

# represents the actual work
async def worker_task(index):
    try:
        print(f"i am worker {index} and i am starting")
        await asyncio.sleep(index)

        if index % 9 == 0:
            print('simulating error')
            raise NotImplementedError("some error happened")

        print(f"i am worker {index} and i am done")
    except:
        # put this work back on the pile (fudge the index so it doesn't throw this time)
        work_todo.append(worker_task(index + 1))
        

# gets the next 'concurrent' workload segment (if there is one)
def get_next_tasks():
    todo = []

    i = 0

    while i < CONCURRENT_TASK_LIMIT and len(work_todo) > 0:
        todo.append(work_todo.pop())
        i += 1

    return todo

# drains down any outstanding tasks and closes the loop
async def are_we_done_yet():
    print('draining')
    
    await asyncio.gather(*work_in_progress)

    if (len(work_todo)) > 0:
        loop.create_task(work())
        print('found some retries')
    else:
        loop.stop()
        # closes out the program
        print('done')
    
    

# puts work on the queue every tick (1 second)
async def work():
    next_tasks = get_next_tasks()
    if len(next_tasks) > 0:
        print(f'found {len(next_tasks)} tasks to do')
        for task in next_tasks:
            # schedules the work, puts it in the in-progress pile
            work_in_progress.append(loop.create_task(task))

        # this is the 'tick' or speed work gets scheduled on
        await asyncio.sleep(ONE_SECOND)
        
        # every 'tick' we add this tasks onto the loop again unless there isn't any more to do...
        loop.create_task(work())
    else:
        # ... if there isn't any to do we just enter drain mode
        await are_we_done_yet()

# bootstrap the process
create_tasks()
loop.create_task(work())
loop.run_forever()
```

This just simulates something going wrong and `re-queues` the failed task. If the error happens after the main `work` method has finished it won't get re-queued so in the `are-we-there-yet` method it would need to check and rerun any failed tasks - this isn't particularly optimal as it'll wait to drain before checking everything else but gives you an idea of *an implementation*

Comment: I like this approach. Would it be possible to handle exception at task level. 
Like if a worker_task fails then i can add it back to work_todo.

Comment: Added a second example with a simulated exception - it doesn't really meet your requirement for 'as fast as possible' in some scenarios though but does demo the concept a bit.

Comment: looks really great! thx. What's the purpose of the if block in are_we_done_yet ? Cause asyncio.gather is supposed to resolve every coroutines. Can't we directly write loop.stop after the ayncio.gather ?

Comment: I think `gather` will only do the ones it knew about at the time it was called (it takes an iterable of tasks rather than a live list), I think this can get into a situation where retries at the *very* end of a run might not get picked up so it just checks them again at the end just in case.